# Given a query image Q and two other images X and Y, how to determine which one is most similar to Q?

Tags: algorithms, computer-vision

Given a query image Q and two other images X and Y (you can assume they have more or less the same resolutions if that simplifies the problem), which algorithm would perform extremely well at determining which image between X and Y is most similar to Q, even when the differences are rather subtle? For example, a trivial case would be:

- Q = image of mountains, X = image of mountains, Y = image of dogs, therefore it is clear that sim(Q,X) > sim(Q,Y).

However, examples of trickier cases would be:

- Q = image of a yellow car, X = image of a red car, Y = image of a yellow car, therefore sim(Q,Y) > sim(Q,X) (assuming the car shapes are more or less the same).
- Q = image of a man standing up in the middle with a black background, X = image of another man standing up in the middle with a black background, Y = image of a woman standing up in the middle with a black background, therefore sim(Q,X) > sim(Q,Y).

Which algorithm (or combination of algorithms) would be robust enough to handle even the tricky cases with very high accuracy?

Comment: potential duplicate of https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28840/compare-image-similarity-in-python, or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27795/neural-networks-find-most-similar-images? Also see here an Image Similarity with Siamese Networks
https://www.kaggle.com/kmader/image-similarity-with-siamese-networks